# Prevent type changes when constructing an Array{Any} in Julia

Tags: arrays, type-conversion, julia

I want to make an Array{Any} like this:

```
julia> Array{Any}([false   ,  0.5,  5 ])
3-element Vector{Any}:
 0.0
 0.5
 5.0
```

but it converts the Bool and the integer to floats. But when I have a string it does not do type conversions.

```
julia> Array{Any}([false,0.5,5,"test"])
4-element Vector{Any}:
 false
 0.5
 5
 "test"
```

The easy workaround is to make the array and then do a manual conversion of every entry to the type I originally wrote. Or do the second option and then delete the final  entry. Is there a cleaner (ideally one line) way to make the array in exactly the types I originally wrote though?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just do:

```
julia> Any[false, 0.5, 5]
3-element Vector{Any}:
 false
     0.5
     5
```

Note that:

```
julia> [false, 0.5, 5]
3-element Vector{Float64}:
 0.0
 0.5
 5.0
```

Hence it is creating a `Vector` of `Float64` because this is a type that captures all value and wrapping that with `Vector{Any}()` was too late.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't care about types and compilation acceleration you can just write:

```
julia> [false,0.5,5,"test"]
4-element Vector{Any}:
 false
 0.5
 5
 "test"
```

If you care a little more about types you could use this:

```
julia> a = Union{Bool, Float64, Int, String}[false, 0.5, 5, "test"]
4-element Vector{Union{Bool, Float64, Int64, String}}:
 false
 0.5
 5
 "test"
```

It's better but not great. Heterogenous arrays are not a good practice in Julia. Structuring your data by using [composite types](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/types/#Composite-Types) or [tuples](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/types/#Tuple-Types) makes things more readable (and self-documented) and can potentially improve your performance.